# URI is not registered

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I just make it with a simple [Java Project of mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/), and now i want to read this file and make a pdf with another Java Web project, but xml give me this errors..

The error was on 2 lines in jasperPrint tag : 
**xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print"**

**Error :** URI is not registered

The file is a JasperReportfile XML (jrxml)

And in 4 line also inside JasperPring tag : http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperprint.xsd

**Error :** Cannot resolve symbol http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperprint.xsd

How can i solve them? The link was broken, but i don't know another link to put there

**testReport.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperPrint
        xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print
        http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperprint.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" topMargin="10" leftMargin="10" bottomMargin="10" rightMargin="10" locale="it_IT" timezone="Europe/Berlin">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.start.page.index" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.end.page.index" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.page.count" value="1"/>
    <origin band="title"/>
    <origin band="columnHeader"/>
    <origin band="detail"/>
    <origin band="pageFooter"/>
    <style name="style_19_" forecolor="#000000" fontName="SansSerif" fontSize="10">
        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
    </style>
    <style name="style_23_" style="style_19_">
        <box rightPadding="0">
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="style_26_" style="style_19_">
        <box leftPadding="0">
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <page>
        <text textAlignment="Center" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
            <reportElement uuid="3c49af5c-8777-441d-a3e9-7bc7c7991e63" key="title.textField1" style="style_19_" x="10" y="10" width="575" height="17" origin="0" srcId="1"/>
            <textContent><![CDATA[SimpleReportExample]]></textContent>
        </text>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="ed6eb1b6-9fc6-48b7-8237-97d003db9405" key="columnHeader.list1" x="10" y="27" width="575" height="17" origin="1" srcId="2"/>
            <text textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="1c3a1726-0f28-4c58-9cf7-e01a6b1b4b23" key="columnHeader.column_id.title1" style="style_19_" x="0" y="0" width="143" height="17" origin="1" srcId="3"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Customer Id]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="d8eac707-e5b9-404c-bb1a-3bc234564c11" key="columnHeader.column_first_name.title1" style="style_19_" x="143" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="1" srcId="4"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[First Name]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="cfb7fab8-d514-4e09-beeb-cb65eb0d514f" key="columnHeader.column_last_name.title1" style="style_19_" x="287" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="1" srcId="5"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Last Name]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="af0311bd-fb6c-47f0-b6b5-cdefc7e86dfc" key="columnHeader.column_date.title1" style="style_19_" x="431" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="1" srcId="6"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Date]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="9f8b3fe3-790c-4df5-9dde-3ac805cdacf4" key="detail.list1" x="10" y="44" width="575" height="17" origin="2" srcId="7"/>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.lang.Integer" pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement uuid="e207b5bf-fc80-4532-9e92-0f90a24a9948" key="detail.column_id1" style="style_19_" x="0" y="0" width="143" height="17" origin="2" srcId="8"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[1]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a7f8f4e5-83f3-4afe-9bc0-8fc1a1fcf7dd" key="detail.column_first_name1" style="style_19_" x="143" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="9"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Ricardo]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a32eff89-3088-4501-833f-50579e0f9cef" key="detail.column_last_name1" style="style_19_" x="287" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="10"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Mariaca]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.sql.Date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="402b3f38-c753-45a0-90ce-a529c6d9f6e4" key="detail.column_date1" style="style_19_" x="431" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="11"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[12/03/2015]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="9f8b3fe3-790c-4df5-9dde-3ac805cdacf4" key="detail.list1" x="10" y="61" width="575" height="17" origin="2" srcId="7"/>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.lang.Integer" pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement uuid="e207b5bf-fc80-4532-9e92-0f90a24a9948" key="detail.column_id1" style="style_19_" x="0" y="0" width="143" height="17" origin="2" srcId="8"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[2]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a7f8f4e5-83f3-4afe-9bc0-8fc1a1fcf7dd" key="detail.column_first_name1" style="style_19_" x="143" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="9"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[YONG]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a32eff89-3088-4501-833f-50579e0f9cef" key="detail.column_last_name1" style="style_19_" x="287" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="10"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[MOOK KIM]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.sql.Date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="402b3f38-c753-45a0-90ce-a529c6d9f6e4" key="detail.column_date1" style="style_19_" x="431" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="11"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[12/03/2015]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="9f8b3fe3-790c-4df5-9dde-3ac805cdacf4" key="detail.list1" x="10" y="78" width="575" height="17" origin="2" srcId="7"/>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.lang.Integer" pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement uuid="e207b5bf-fc80-4532-9e92-0f90a24a9948" key="detail.column_id1" style="style_19_" x="0" y="0" width="143" height="17" origin="2" srcId="8"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[3]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a7f8f4e5-83f3-4afe-9bc0-8fc1a1fcf7dd" key="detail.column_first_name1" style="style_19_" x="143" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="9"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Enrico]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="a32eff89-3088-4501-833f-50579e0f9cef" key="detail.column_last_name1" style="style_19_" x="287" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="10"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Viale]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656" valueClass="java.sql.Date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="402b3f38-c753-45a0-90ce-a529c6d9f6e4" key="detail.column_date1" style="style_19_" x="431" y="0" width="144" height="17" origin="2" srcId="11"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[12/09/2015]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="51f4a901-1fff-4b27-802d-6b71e8038915" key="pageFooter.list1" x="10" y="815" width="575" height="17" origin="3" srcId="12"/>
            <text textAlignment="Right" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="3248a9b4-3d8e-455f-bfe9-cd278f495a47" key="pageFooter.textField1" style="style_23_" x="0" y="0" width="287" height="17" origin="3" srcId="13"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[1]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Left" textHeight="12.578125" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-2.1972656">
                <reportElement uuid="d30fdba0-912e-42e0-bb64-b42ee66334bb" key="pageFooter.textField2" style="style_26_" x="287" y="0" width="288" height="17" origin="3" srcId="14"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[ of 1]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
    </page>
</jasperPrint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are assuming that this is a **.jrxml** file?, but it is not, *jrxml files starts with tag jasperReport*!

This is a **jrpxml**!

Quoting @Robert Mugattarov

> **.jrpxml** is a human readable XML representation of a `JasperPrint` object
>   i.e. an XML version of a template that **has been filled** with data. This
>   file can be unmarshalled back into a `JasperPrint` object

To **unmarshal** it back to the `JasperPrint` you can use:

```
JasperPrint myPrint = JRPrintXmlLoader.load("testReport.jrpxml");
```

To generate for example a **pdf**

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(myPrint, "testReport.pdf");
```

The **result** will be:

[image: Result]